# Converting a String into an Object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm receiving a string like `obj{a="foo",b="bar",c=3,d=4.0}` inside a nodejs environment I'm working in and I'm trying to convert this String into a reference-able Object like this:

```
{
    a : "foo",
    b : "bar",
    c : 3,
    d : 4.0
}
```

Assigned to `obj` of course.

I've used a myriad of formatting tricks but whenever I call JSON.parse() I get unexpected character errors. Usually on the first alpha-character it sees.

My next step is to write several nested loops to make all of the assignments manually but I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction on how to parse this.

EDIT: Ok there's a little more to the story and I thought I should omit it but I guess explaining everything would be helpful.

The actual data packet that I'm receiving looks like this.

`ack{a="000000061",b=0,c=2.0}\rb{a=244.0,b=255,c=4.0}\rc{a=6.0,b=55,c=55}endack;`

So yeah that's the actual string I'm trying to parse into three distinct accessible Objects. I know I'm having a brain fart from a long day but yeah it's giving me a run for my money right now.

Comment: Why not use *actual* JSON for the text? (The string shown is *not* JSON; what is it?)

Comment: What is ``obj``? If that's a global variable, this serialization format seems vulnerable to ``eval``-like intrusions.

Comment: First suggestion.  When a format for defining objects already exists and has well tested code built into your environment, try like heck to use the existing JSON format and parsing code rather than creating your own format that you then have to build your own parser for.  There really is no excuse to reinvent the wheel here.  Every other environment nowadays knows how to create JSON because it is now a universal interchange format.

Comment: `obj` is literally just some characters preceding the rest of the text. This data is coming from another computer at my work that simply reports various measurements in the format that I showed.

Comment: In the spirit of being helpful, while a bit hacky, go ahead and use regex (something like `/^(.+)\{/` to match the first set of characters. then you can remove them from the string using substring. then parse what remains, and assign it to a property of a variable, like `context[ varname ] = JSON.parse(remainder)`

Comment: @Catalyst that's where I was headed but I didn't get it to the finish line before I had to leave work. It's still bothering me which is why I'm trying to work out now at home.

Comment: I added some more details to the entirety of the task. I regret omitting them to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace the "=" with ":" and remove the obj infront

```
str = str.replace(/=/g, ":").replace("obj{", "{")
```

Since it's not in correct json format (but can be read by js parser) we can't use JSON.parse but we can use eval

```
eval("var obj = " + str);
```

Obvious there are some assumptions with this technique such that = always mean colon and you won't have obj{ as text (but the latter can be fixed with a simple substring method)

Keep in mind eval is also considered evil so use at your own risk.  Imagine if the user were to send bad data, they could easily get into your parser and run something malicious.  But hopefully this will give you an idea or inspiration to a better solution.

You can go a step further and use

```
str = 'obj{a="foo",b="bar",c=3,d=4.0}'
str = str.substr(3,str.length).replace(/([{,])([\w])=/g, '$1\"$2\":');
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: I swear I tried this and a myriad of other things but just couldn't get it to work! I messed around with everything and got the JSON.parse() avenue to work though. The data coming through is very predictable, a few strings and floats so eval won't be necessary. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thanks a lot. To avoid eval and to preserve the name I used this combination:
`p = str.split("{");`
`m[p[0]] = JSON.parse("{\"" + p[1].replace(/=/g, "\":").replace(/,/g, ",\""));`
Where `m` is a different object accessible globally.